# Accessing a local variable of a function from another function

Tags: javascript, scope

Using the following code how can I access `a` from inside log2?

```
   (function() {
     function log() {
       var a = "string";
     }
     log()

     function log2() {
       console.log(log.a);
     }

     console.log(log);
     log2();
   })()
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: I'm sorry I posted from my phone

Comment: It will be easy to post the bin instead of the image

Comment: Which were your your attempts, did you tried anything already? Show us concrete code, not an image of it, that way it can be easily reused and edited just by copying it!

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared with the `var` keyword in JavaScript are function-scoped. This means that they cannot be accessed from outside the function they were declared in without returning them. The solution is to declare the variable within your outer immediately-invoked function, which will enclose the variable and make it available to the two inner functions:

```
(function() {
  var a;

  function inner1 () {
    a = 'string';
  }

  function inner2 () {
    console.log(a);
  }

  inner1();
  inner2(); // => logs 'string'
})()

console.log(a); // => logs undefined, because a is enclosed
```